# Image control doesn't show image

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, imageurl

I have an Image control in my asp.net page. I gave an image url from properties window but when I run my application, the image doesn't shown. The source code is here:

```
 <asp:Image ID="imgMain" runat="server" 
        ImageUrl="~/ProductImages/Larges/Hydrangeas.jpg" />
```

And I am sure of the path is correct. I can see the picture on file explorer when I copy the image url from browser's source code.

Do you have any idea?

Comment: Check source of your page and find imgMain to get what image path you have click it to ensure path is correct

Comment: Run it in IE if it shows an error cross image in place of your image then it must be path related problem.

Comment: @Adil, I checked it and it is true path. As I said, I gave path from properties window of Image control.

Comment: Checking the source HTML can help, As your image is not getting displayed so there must be something wrong, Can you get HTML tag from source and show us?

Comment: <img id="imgMain" src="D:\Projeler\DOS\trunk\Dos.Application\Dos.Web.UI\ProductImages\Thumbs\Hydrangeas.jpg" /> I edited my question. I can see the picture on file explorer with this path.

Comment: It should be URL of the image, not physical path. Find out absolute URL of the image (like "http:// www.../Hydrangeas.jpg") and just put it to the browser to check that IIS can send you that image back, then put this absolute url to ImageUrl property, if it works, only then make the URL shorter using ~ alias.

Comment: You have done something on code behind for sure ! Its not possible to get on src the physical path with this code.

Comment: I think If I'm correct you should use ../ProductImages/Larges/Hydrangeas.jpg here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that your original URL in the question is correct.

Without knowing anything more, I would start by checking if it's an autorization issue:

- When you debug this issue, are you logged in to the site? If not try to log in first.
- When logged in, check that the logged in user is authorized to access content from the path in question.

Also try to copy the URL on the image tag in the rendered page and paste it directly in the address bar of your browser. What happens?

Answer (score 1):

I found that since my website was being launched as the Default Web Site, I had to also add the file in C:\inetpub\wwwroot***. *** represents the directory structure for the file location. Once I did that, the image then displayed via the browser.